# How to Implement (if Possible) an Artifical Neural Network with an Output with Multiple (>2) Possibilities?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-network

For example, let's say that we can classify all planets into water, earth, and air.  Each of these can be identified by a number of quantitative characteristics, such as albedo, size, and temperature, which range in values from 1-10 and are distinct for each type of planet.  If I have inputs for these characteristics, how do I format the neural network's output to output a result as water, earth, or air?

From my (limited) knowledge, my experience tells me that there are at max only two outputs to an artificial neural network that will, at the end, only result true or false (or indeterminate). With one output, there are step functions where the output is 1 if the threshold is crossed, and 0 if the threshold is not crossed, or linear/sigmoidal that can also determine indeterminate.  With two outputs, if one output is larger than the other, then the overall output is 1 or 0.

How would I implement a neural network with more than two overall outputs?  My scope is only a true/false output, although I feel that the solution may be quite simple (and something that I overlooked).  Furthermore, are there any resources to help me with this?  The queries I've made haven't been the most successful.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the step function on the output; once you remove this you have a real-valued output that you can treat in several different ways:

- Set ranges of values that are interpreted as each different output. So, 0...0.3 is output 1, 0.3...0.6 is output 2 and 0.6...1.0 is output 3. You would then train for outputs 0, 0.5 and 1.0 for the three possible outputs.
- Use three independent networks or three output nodes to predict each of the outputs. Then, the output is considered to be the network that gives the highest result.

Comment: I was thinking about the range of values suggestion, but would that work if the input qualities are independent of each other?  Because initially, an output of 0.2 that equals earth could as easily be an output of 0.8 that equals earth.

Comment: Also, I can see how the three independent networks system works.  What happens, however, if there are many more than three (maybe 20, 30, or more) different possible outputs?  My guess would be that that solution would no longer be applicable.

Comment: @TheObscureQuestion Why would having 30 possible outputs eliminate the possibility of having multiple neural networks? You might have more trouble getting enough training data to classify into 30 classes, but that is data problem not a problem with the technique. (A decision tree might work better in that case.)

Comment: @TheObscureQuestion With regard to your first question, you may be misunderstanding things. If the output is earth then I will *always* train it to output (say) 0. When the training is complete, the network will hopefully return something close to zero when earth is the right answer. The drawback of this approach is that if something looks halfway like output 0 and half like output 2, you could easily end up returning output 1 because it is the average of the two that should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Artificial Neural Networks (ANNs) are not limited to one or two outputs. The number of outputs is only limited by your available computing resources.

A commonly used convention for multi-class classification (more than two classes) with [multilayer perceptrons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_perceptron) is to have as many outputs as there are classes and to have the desired network outputs be all zeros except for a unity output in the output node corresponding to the target class. For example, if there are 5 classes, the desired network output for class 2 would be `(0, 1, 0, 0, 0)` and the desired output for class 5 would be `(0, 0, 0, 0, 1)`. This is the case where the classes are considered mutually exclusive.

But you could also define your target outputs to have more than one unity value. For example, if output 1 corresponds to "mammal" and output 4 corresponds to "dog", then you could specify the output for a Beagle (a kind of dog) to be `(1, 0, 0, 1, 0)`. How you map the outputs to your target classes is up to you. The trick is setting up the network architecture (number & sizes of layers) so that your classes are learnable.

Answer (score 0):

Is cases of classification as this, best performances are reached using three discrete output units in the form (a, b, c) where a, b and c can have values 0 or 1. Prepare your training set for a network with three output units and setting the right property for each record.

Generally, it's used the "winner takes all" rule (the higher value wins and give you the final category) but I prefer to use ROC curves to analyze results.

Be careful with number of hidden units a layers. Multiple outputs are possible without problems (not limited to 2) but more outputs means more training data, fixed number of hidden units and intermediate layers, to reach an acceptable result (curse of dimensionality problem).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have **n** classes. Then you can implement the output layer as a [Softmax Regression Layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_activation_function) of **n** units instead of a regular Logistic Regression Layer.

Comment: Please add additional information with how to use the link you provided, as we would like to maintain usability in the event that the link gets broken in the future.